# how to implement gesture-based menu

Tags: menu

I am supposed to implement a gesture-based menu in which you scroll through a horizontal list of items by panning or flinging through them. This kind of menus is very common in smart phone games. Example case would be Cut the Rope where you select box (Cardboard box, Fabric box) or Angry Birds where you select the set of levels (Poached Eggs, Mighty Hoax).

What I am thinking is that I'll have to do some complex physics calculations and give velocities and accelerations to menu items based on the gestures. Any better solutions? I am using libgdx btw.

Comment: You may find this link useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613938/ios-drag-flick-or-fling-a-uiview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you'd need to go through all that to implement a simple menu! It's all about defining offsets for various items (I'll just assume you want Cut the Rope-style menus, with only one entry in sight at a given moment (excluding transitions)) and then **tweening** between those offsets whenever a flick is detected!

You seem to have the gesture system all wired up, so right now, we just need to figure out how to display the menu. *For simplicity's sake, we'll just assume that we don't want the menu to wrap around.*

We'll start by envisioning what this menu will look like, in our heads. It would be just like a filmstrip which passes through the phone and can be seen through the screen.

```
                   phone ("stuff" is currently selected)
                  ========  
 |---------------|        |-------|
 | Start | About | Stuff  | Quit  |
 |---------------|        |-------|
                 |        |
                 |        |
                 |        |
                  ========
```

We'll just assume that the screen width is **`w`** and, consequently, all menu entries are exactly that width (think Cut the Rope again!).

Now, when "Start", is to be displayed, we should just render the flimstrip on the screen starting with the first element, "Start", while the rest would, theoretically, lie to the right of the screen. This will be considered the basic case, rendering the menu with the **offset = 0**.

Yes, yes, this offset will be the key to our little slidey-slidey menu! Now, it's pretty obvious that when about is selected, we'll just have to offset the "filmstrip" to the left by one "frame", and here **offset = - 1 * frameWidth**. Our example case illustrated by my brilliant ASCII art has the third menu item selected, and since the frames are indexed starting from 0, we'll just subtract two times the frameWidth and get the desired offset. We'll just render the menu starting at offset = -2 * frameWidth.

(Obviously you can just compute frameWidth in advance, by using the API to fetch the screen width, and then just drawing the menu element text/ graphic centered).

So this is pretty simple:

- the user sweeps to the left, we need to get to the menu closer to offset 0, we reduce the index of the selected entity by one and the menu then jumps to the right position
- the user sweeps to the right, we increase the index (obviously as long as it doesn't go over the number of menu elements - 1)

**But what about smooth tweens?**
Libgdx thankfully has interpolations all set for nice little tweens. We just need to take care of a few things so we don't shoot ourselves in the leg. I'll list them here.

*One quick note:*
The Cut the Rope level selector works a tad differently than what I'm saying here. It doesn't just react to flicks (pre-defined gestures), rather it's more sensitive. You can probably achieve a similar effect by playing with offsets and tracking the position of the finger on the screen. (If the user dragged a menu entry too much to the left/right, transition to the previous/next automatically) Friendly advice: just set up a simple, working menu, and leave details like this towards the end, since they can end up taking *a lot* of time! :P

**Alright, back on track!**

What we have now is a way to quickly switch between offsets. We just need to **tween**. There are some additional members that come into play, but I think they're pretty self-explanatory. While we're transitioning between two elements, we remember the "old" offset, and the one we're heading towards, as well as remembering the time we have left from the transition, and we use these four variables to compute the offset (using a libgdx interpolation, exp10 in this case) at the current moment, resulting in a smooth animation.

Let's see, I've created a quick'n'dirty **mock-up**. I've commented the code as best as I could, so I hope the following snippet speaks for itself! :D

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Interpolation;

public class MenuManager {

// The list of the entries being iterated over
private ArrayList<MenuEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();

// The current selected thingy
private int index;

// The menu offset
private float offset = 0.0f;

// Offset of the old menu position, before it started tweening to the new one
private float oldOffset = 0.0f;

// What we're tweening towards
private float targetOffset = 0.0f;

// Hardcoded, I know, you can set this in a smarter fashion to suit your
// needs - it's basically as wide as the screen in my case
private float entryWidth = 400.0f;

// Whether we've finished tweening
private boolean finished = true;

// How much time a single transition should take
private float transitionTimeTotal = 0.33f;

// How much time we have left from the current transition
private float transitionTimeLeft = 0.0f;

// libgdx helper to nicely interpolate between the current and the next 
// positions
private Interpolation interpolation = Interpolation.exp10;

public void addEntry(MenuEntry entry) {
    entries.add(entry);
}

// Called to initiate transition to the next element in the menu
public void selectNext() {
    // Don't do anything if we're still animationg
    if(!finished) return;

    if(index < entries.size() - 1) {
        index++;
        // We need to head towards the next "frame" of the "filmstrip"
        targetOffset = oldOffset + entryWidth;
        finished = false;
        transitionTimeLeft = transitionTimeTotal;
    } else {
        // (does nothing now, menu doesn't wrap around)
        System.out.println("Cannot go to menu entry > entries.size()!");
    }
}

// see selectNext()
public void selectPrevious() {
    if(!finished) return;

    if(index > 0) {
        index --;
        targetOffset = oldOffset - entryWidth;
        finished = false;
        transitionTimeLeft = transitionTimeTotal;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Cannot go to menu entry <0!");
    }
}

// Called when the user selects someting (taps the menu, presses a button, whatever)
public void selectCurrent() {
    if(!finished) {
        System.out.println("Still moving, hold yer pants!");
    } else {
        entries.get(index).select();
    }
}

public void update(float delta) {

    if(transitionTimeLeft > 0.0f) {
        // if we're still transitioning

        transitionTimeLeft -= delta;
        offset = interpolation.apply(oldOffset, targetOffset, 1 - transitionTimeLeft / transitionTimeTotal);
    } else {
        // Transition is over but we haven't handled it yet
        if(!finished) {
            transitionTimeLeft = 0.0f;
            finished = true;
            oldOffset = targetOffset;
        }
    }
}

// Todo make font belong to menu
public void draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, BitmapFont font) {
    if(!finished) {
        // We're animating, just iterate through everything and draw it,
        // it's not like we're wasting *too* much CPU power
        for(int i = 0; i < entries.size(); i++) {
            entries.get(i).draw((int)(i * entryWidth - offset), 100, spriteBatch, font);
        }
    } else {
        // We're not animating, just draw the active thingy
        entries.get(index).draw(0, 100, spriteBatch, font);
    }
}
```

}

And I believe a simple text-based menu entry that can draw itself would suffice! (**do mind the dirty hard-coded text-wrap width!**)

```
public class MenuEntry {


private String label;
// private RenderNode2D graphic;
private Action action;

public MenuEntry(String label, Action action) {
    this.label = label;
    this.action = action;
}

public void select() {
    this.action.execute();
}

public void draw(int x, int y, SpriteBatch spriteBatch, BitmapFont font) {
    font.drawMultiLine(spriteBatch, label, x, y, 400, HAlignment.CENTER);
}
```

}

Oh, and **Action** is just a thingy that has an execute method and, well, represents an action.

```
public interface Action {
abstract void execute();
```

}

Feel free to ask any related question in the comments, and I'll try to clarify what's needed.
Hope this helps!